# /help <pluginname> works, actual command returns nothing. Minecraft 1.14.4 plugin

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I'm trying to code a minecraft plugin in 1.14.4, and `/help firstplugin` works, but `/hello` doesn't send any message.

My Main.Java:

```java
package com.Epic_Waffle.firstplugin;

import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import com.mojang.brigadier.Command;

import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin{
    
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        System.out.println("FirstPlugin successfully enabled!");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        System.out.println("FirstPlugin disabled with no errors!");
    }
    
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        System.out.print(cmd);
        if(cmd.toString().equals("/hello")) {
            if(sender instanceof Player) {
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "Hello!" + ChatColor.GREEN + player.getName() + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Your health has been restored!");
                player.setHealth(20.0);
                
                
            } else {
                System.out.println("You cannot use this command through console.");
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

My plugin.yml

```
version: 1.0
name: FirstPlugin
main: com.Epic_Waffle.firstplugin.Main
author: Epic_Waffle
description: FirstPlugin
commands:
  hello:
    aliases: []
    description: Cool hello command!
```

Comment: does the command print out like `System.out.print(cmd);` suggests it should? What does it print? Does it have the leading slash?

Comment: Try using  `cmd.getName()` instead of `cmd.toString()`. Note that the slash will not be included though. https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/command/Command.html#getName()

Comment: @Jon nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register each command by using the Spigot API before it will be called (see the onEnable method below). You already performed the first step by adding the command to plugin.yml. I also included the documentation for this method call below. Even though these are the docs of 1.16, no changes have been made with regards to registering a CommandExecutor since 1.14. Make sure the object that you try to register implements `CommandExecutor`.

```
public void setExecutor​(@Nullable
CommandExecutor executor)
Sets the CommandExecutor to run when parsing this command
Parameters:
executor - New executor to run
```

[Source for the documentation above](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/command/PluginCommand.html#setExecutor(org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor)).

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    this.getCommand("hello").setExecutor( this );
    System.out.println("FirstPlugin successfully enabled!");
}
```

Additionally I suggest using `Command#getName()` instead of  `toString()` in your onCommand method as stated in my comment.

Comment: where would i put the cmd executor? in the main class?

Comment: You can choose where you put it. But generally if you need a lot of logic, it's considered better to use a different class for that. In your use case it would be fine in the main class indeed.